# How to remove a post from results by ID after query?

Tags: posts, wp-query

If `$posts` contains the results of a `WP_Query` for posts, how can I remove one specific post by ID from the object?

I am not talking about using `post__not_in` prior to the query. I am talking about removing one post *after* the results are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work?

```
// Assuming $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_to_remove = 123;
// If using post objects
foreach ( $posts->posts as $i => $post ) {
  if ( $post_to_remove == $post->ID ) {
    unset( $posts->posts[$i] );
    break; // no need to continue the loop as the post has been found
  }
}
// If only IDs were queried
foreach ( $posts->posts as $i => $post_id ) {
  if ( $post_to_remove == $post_id ) {
    unset( $posts->posts[$i] );
    break; // no need to continue the loop as the post has been found
  }
}
// do your rendering while/for/foreach loop after sorting
```

**EDIT** You could also skip the post in your loop, I think.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php if ( $post_to_remove == get_the_id() ) { continue; } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // Navigation ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php // No Posts Found ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: One issue with the second method (skipping) is that it interferes with my (Javascript) pagination - when I specify N posts per page, there is a blank space where the post in question should be, since this page is then N-1. It does work other than that.

Comment: With your first method, which is proper item removal, where does the Loop go amongst that? Is this essentially switching from a while to a foreach loop?

Comment: About the first example. You would first do your query to get posts, then do the sorting loop and after that do your Loop to display the posts. You can do it in anyway you want - for, foreach or while.

Comment: Not sure how to overcome the blank-slot issue with the first method, but the second method (simply skipping the output when the ID matches an ID to be omitted) is very straightforward.